# Auto rename doesn't work in visual studio c code

Tags: c, variables, reference, visual-studio-2017, rename

i am new on Visual Studio for C language, i worked before for c# by using Visual Studio. Now i'm trying to change a variable automatically entire solution or project by changing just in place where is defined.

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* head = NULL;
//node* temp = NULL;
node* q = NULL;

void AddNodeLast(int newData)
{
    node* add = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    add->data = newData;
    add->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = add;
    else
    {
        q = head;
        while (q->next != NULL)
            q = q->next;
        q->next = add;
    }
}
```

This feature works if i code C# as shown in picture which i put below. But if code C programming language like above and if i want to change "head" variables related to all entire project referances , this isn't working like in C# and same editor??, i searched everywhere but i couldn't find.
[Auto rename doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DomiX.png)
Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about `C` or only about an editor feature?

Comment: this question is actually about editor feature.

Comment: Highlight a variable and press Ctrl+R and rename it. It's not clear what problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmark. İt worked :-) Thing was this which i wanted. But this doesn't work automatically. The point which i don't understand if i change a variable through normal way. Do i always have to press CTRL+R ?

Comment: C# is a high level language, perhaps it's easier for the editor to track variables. I don't think there is a similar option in C or C++ for this type of operation. It's too hard for the editor to be certain of the variable properties without full compile/link each time.